# How to set default to track edits

Tags: google-docs

In Google Docs: "Suggest" mode is the same as MS-Word's tracked changes.

When submitting a document for edits: How to set the edit mode to "Suggest", so as to ensure that the editor does not have to set the mode to "Suggest".

Maybe there is a setting so that all changes are tracked changes?

Comment: Did you change a document to suggest mode and see if there's any difference in the url?